# If logic behind checking two textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I'm attempting to check two input textfields that the user type in  to see if they put in either AM or PM (going for non-case sensitive). If they did, post the event otherwise display an alert.

I tried this, it works in some occasions, but when I type in PM and AM in the second it sometimes tells me it's not valid and returning my alert. Any idea where I got the logic wrong?

```
if(!([self.eventStartTimeSuffix.text isEqualToString:@"AM"] || [self.eventStartTimeSuffix.text isEqualToString:@"PM"]) && !([self.eventEndTimeSuffix.text isEqualToString:@"AM"] || [self.eventEndTimeSuffix.text isEqualToString:@"PM"]))
  {

        NSLog(@"Invalid Event / Start Time Suffix, AM or PM required");


  }

else
{
//post event
}
```

Comment: Try something more along the lines of `[[self.eventStartTimeSuffix.text lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"am"].location != NSNotFound;`

Comment: Agreed with @Putz1103 you're not doing a case-insensitive compare. As written, it will ONLY validate AM or PM, and not am or pm.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to test for *not* AM/PM you are testing for *both* being invalid, your test is: NOT(StartTimeSuffix is AM/PM) AND NOT(EndTimeSuffix is AM/PM). So first either use OR to join the separate conditions or test them independently so you can present a more specific error.

You are also not ignoring case as you say you wish to, and if the user enters some whitespace it might be worth ignoring that as well. You can do both of these with code such as:

```
NSSString *startSuffix = [[self.eventStartTimeSuffix.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] lowercaseString];
```

and then comparing `startSuffix` to `@"am"` and `@"pm"`, likewise for `eventEndTimeSuffix`.

BTW You might be even better off if you use the international facilities of OS X and compare for the localised versions of AM & PM - but that is another topic!

Answer (score 0):

Add parentheses to make your grouping clear:

Pseudocode (this is not real code!):

```
if (
  (startText == "AM" || startText == "PM")
  &&
  (endText == "AM" || endText "PM")
  )
{
  //Both fields contain either "AM" or PM"
}
```

Note that if you want case insensitive comparison, you should use

```
if ([string caseInsensitiveCompare: @"otherString"] == NSOrderedSame)
{
   //strings match, ignoring case
}
else
{
  //strings don't match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may as well factor out a method to make it more readable:

```
- (BOOL)hasValidTimeSuffix:(NSString *)timeText {
    return [[timeText lowercaseString] hasSuffix:@"am"] || [[timeText lowercaseString] hasSuffix:@"pm"]
}
```

and then

```
if ([self hasValidTimeSuffix:self.eventStartTimeSuffix.text] && [self hasValidTimeSuffix:self.eventEndTimeSuffix.text])
{ 
    //post event
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid Event / Start Time Suffix, AM or PM required");
}
```

Notice the use of NSString's `lowercaseString` and `hasSuffix:` methods. These help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you bother checking for the input of textfields? Won't it be wiser to use a NSPopUpButton? Check the selected tag 0:AM or 1:PM. It's just an idea, but it screams for a NSPopUpButton. Cheers!

```
if
    ([sender selectedTag] == AM)
{
    NSLog(@"it's AM");
}
else if([sender selectedTag] == PM)
{
    NSLog(@"it's PM");
}

//Sender is one of the two NSPopUpButtons
//I made a Typedef Enum to make it more readable
/*In the .h file:
 typedef enum {
 AM,
 PM
 } TimeNotation;
 */
```